# Understanding golang channels. All goroutines are asleep - deadlock [Tour of Go, Crawler]

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Probably this is what happens when a PHP-developer who has never dealt with multi-threaded programs starts to learn golang and channels.

I'm on the last exercise of Tour of Go, [[Exercise: Web Crawler]](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10) (I had no problems with other exercises before this one)

I'm trying to write as simple code as possible though,
my Crawl method looks like this:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // kick off crawling by passing initial Url to a Job queue
    Queue <- Job{
        url,
        depth,
    }

    // make sure we close the Queue channel
    defer close(Queue)

    // read from the Queue
    for job := range Queue {
        // if fetched or has hit the bottom of depth,
        // just continue right away to pick up next Job
        if fetched.Has(job.Url) || job.Depth <= 0 {
            continue
        }
        fres := fetcher.Fetch(job.Url)
        fetched.Add(job.Url, fres)
        for i := range fres.Urls {
            // send new urls just fetched from current url in Job
            // to the Queue
            Queue <- Job{
                fres.Urls[i], job.Depth - 1,
            }
        }
    }

    for _, res := range fetched.m {
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

`go run` says I should not write any `go` code and get back to `PHP`:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.Crawl(0xf37c1, 0x12, 0x4, 0x1600e0, 0x104401c0, 0x104000f0)
    /tmp/sandbox452918312/main.go:64 +0x80
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox452918312/main.go:87 +0x60
```

Of course, I have googled this problem and the conclusion is usually: "close your chans", which I did (did I?).

So, can somebody point out what am I missing here?

The complete code is here: https://play.golang.org/p/-98SdVndD6

What is the most idiomatic golang way for this exercise? I've found a handful of them.

- [by avalanche123](https://gist.github.com/avalanche123/4127253)
- [by fgrehm](https://github.com/fgrehm/go-tour/blob/master/73-web-crawler-golang-team-solution.go)
- https://play.golang.org/p/Zovub8KdL-

etc. which one seems to be a clean solution to you?

Also, should I use channels **only** with goroutines?

Comment: I don't have time right now for a complete answer, but an unbuffered channel blocks until the corresponding receive is done. When you send the job on the `Queue` channel, it waits for the object to be received, which isn't going to happen because you try to receive it later in that same function. You might want to read more about channels here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels.

Answer (score 1):

You're 'defer'ring the closing of the queue. This means "Close the Queue when this function (Crawl) exits!"

Then you enter a loop that will block until it either:

1. Receives an item OR
2. 'Queue' is closed

There is a 'Job' added to the queue at the beginning (this would allow the loop to run a single time), then at the end of the first run, the loop will block until either of the above two conditions are met once again.

*Note: The run through the first loop could potentially add more items to the queue (and therefore cause more iterations), at some point though, the loop's queue will be exhausted and the loop will once again block waiting for one of the above two conditions*

However, there are never any more items added to the queue (so #1 fails) and the 'Queue' is only closed after this function exits, which cannot happen until after the loop exits (so #2 fails).

**TLDR:** Your loop is waiting for your function to exit, and your function is waiting for your loop to exit - Deadlock

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I guess things are even worse with my code. It took me a whole day to understand exactly what **unbuffered channels** are and how they work. By `things are worse` I mean the code will not even reach first loop, even defer statement: https://play.golang.org/p/G96SoHdgUB I've taught myself on how unbuffered channels are blocking with the following code I wrote: https://play.golang.org/p/ZFTSTrMDeA Now I've got an idea how to re-write code, but way too tired today learning go :)

Comment: And yes, second link to a playground is a good example of memory leak in go since goroutine will stay in memory forever (wont be gc'ed) and I don't think things will change since there is (presumably) no acceptable way to gc such hanging goroutines https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19702